# Failed to execute goal on project itconnect: Could not resolve dependencies

Tags: java, maven, spring-mvc, heroku

I'm geting this error

> Failed to execute goal on project itconnect: Could not resolve
> dependencies for project
> com.itconnectstartup:itconnect:war:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT: Could not find
> artifact com.itconnectstartup:itconnectbackend:jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT

when I try to execute the command: `mvn package`. I linked my backendproject witch called "itconnectbackend" to my frontendproject called "itconnect" in POM.XML file of frontendproject:

```
FRONTEND POM.XML FILE
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

  <groupId>com.itconnectstartup</groupId>
  <artifactId>itconnectbackend</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <packaging>jar</packaging>

  <name>itconnectbackend</name>
  <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>

  <properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <spring.version>4.3.6.RELEASE</spring.version>
  </properties>

  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>junit</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
      <version>3.8.1</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    
   <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-context-support</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.mail</groupId>
            <artifactId>mail</artifactId>
            <version>1.4.7</version>
        </dependency>
    <!-- SPRING MVC DEPENDENCY -->
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework/spring-webmvc -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        
  </dependencies>
  
  <build>
  <plugins>
  <!-- UPDATE TO LATEST JAVA -->
            <plugin>

                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.8</source>
                    <target>1.8</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            
            
            
             <!-- Web runner dependency -->
            
        
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <phase>package</phase>
                    <goals><goal>copy</goal></goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <artifactItems>
                            <artifactItem>
                                <groupId>com.heroku</groupId>
                                <artifactId>webapp-runner</artifactId>
                                <version>9.0.52.1</version>
                                <destFileName>webapp-runner.jar</destFileName>
                            </artifactItem>
                        </artifactItems>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
  
  </plugins>
  
  
  </build>
</project>
```

BACKEND POM.XML FILE

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

  <groupId>com.itconnectstartup</groupId>
  <artifactId>itconnectbackend</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <packaging>jar</packaging>

  <name>itconnectbackend</name>
  <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>

  <properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <spring.version>4.3.6.RELEASE</spring.version>
  </properties>

  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>junit</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
      <version>3.8.1</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    
   <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-context-support</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.mail</groupId>
            <artifactId>mail</artifactId>
            <version>1.4.7</version>
        </dependency>
    <!-- SPRING MVC DEPENDENCY -->
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework/spring-webmvc -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        
  </dependencies>
  
  <build>
  <plugins>
  <!-- UPDATE TO LATEST JAVA -->
            <plugin>

                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.8</source>
                    <target>1.8</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            
            
            
             <!-- Web runner dependency -->
            
        
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <phase>package</phase>
                    <goals><goal>copy</goal></goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <artifactItems>
                            <artifactItem>
                                <groupId>com.heroku</groupId>
                                <artifactId>webapp-runner</artifactId>
                                <version>9.0.52.1</version>
                                <destFileName>webapp-runner.jar</destFileName>
                            </artifactItem>
                        </artifactItems>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
  
  </plugins>
  
  
  </build>
</project>
```

Answer (score 0):

First you have to build the backend using `mvn clean istall` which puts the backend artefact into you local maven repository where it can fetched from the backend.
`mvn clean package` is not sufficent